# Convert one JPA entity to another

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, adapter

What is the best way to convert one JPA entity to another?

This is necessitated by a temporary workaround where a subset of entity instances with specific criteria need to be translated and persisted as entities of a different type.

I have attempted this with a somewhat non-traditional Adapter class (does not share common interface):

```
public class JediKnightToSithLordAdapter extends SithLord {
  public JediKnightToSithLordAdapter(JediKnight jediKnight) {
     // call setter methods
  }
}
```

However this leads to a "Non-entity object instance passed to evict" IllegalArgumentException.

I have also considered the following:

Use the standard Adapter pattern to create an interface that is implemented by both the original entity and the adapter class (however, this workaround is only temporary and will therefore lead to unnecessary clutter)

OR

Add a static conversion method to the target entity class

```
@Entity
public class SithLord {
    // ... 

    public static SithLord of(JediKnight jediKnight) {
        SithLord sithLord = new SithLord();
        // populate sithLord fields
        return sithLord;
    }
}
```

OR

Should the static method be moved to a separate Converter/Translator class?

Is there another, better textbook approach for doing this?

Comment: i would go for the `static conversion method` because you won't need a new class for it

Comment: FWIW Nothing to do with JPA, which simply persists the objects given to it. This is Java, and nothing else